# Strange visual bug happening on QFocusEvents in my child QLineEdit

Tags: python, class, pyqt5

I'm making this class to make my QEditLines to have a default value, that will work as a label for the line, it seems to be working, but when changing the focus with 'Tab' the line will add a '|' at the end of the line and keep it until restarting and it's just visual, it doesn't change the Entry's value.

My child class of QLineEdit:

```
class Entry(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, frame: QtWidgets.QFrame):
        super(Entry, self).__init__(frame)
        self.default_text = ''

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QFocusEvent)
    def focusInEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QFocusEvent) -> None:
        if self.text() == self.default_text:
            self.clear()
            if 'PASSWORD' in self.default_text:
                self.setEchoMode(self.Password)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QFocusEvent)
    def focusOutEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QFocusEvent) -> None:
        if self.text() == "":
            self.setText(self.default_text)
            if 'PASSWORD' in self.default_text:
                self.setEchoMode(self.Normal)
```

can be reproducible with a simple GUI with the code below:

```
def print_value(entry: Entry, entry2: Entry):
    print(entry.text())
    print(entry2.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    root.resize(500,500)
    frame = QtWidgets.QWidget(root)
    frame.resize(500,500)
    entry = Entry(frame)
    entry.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 100, 50))
    entry.setText('PASSWORD')
    entry.default_text = 'PASSWORD'
    entry2 = Entry(frame)
    entry2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 100, 50))
    entry2.setText('USERNAME')
    entry2.default_text = 'USERNAME'
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(frame)
    button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 200, 50, 50))
    button.pressed.connect(lambda: print_value(entry, entry2))
    root.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the terminal is the output of the values in the Entry objects, Password, and USERNAME QLineEdits. [Screenshot]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/arKpv.png]

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm sorry, I'm new to the site. I found it to be reproducible with a code with 42 lines if it is what you meant, I can add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of focusInEvent and focusOutEvent has the task of enabling and disabling the cursor, but by override those methods you are eliminating that behavior. One possible solution is to also invoke the default implementation:

```
class Entry(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, frame: QtWidgets.QFrame):
        super(Entry, self).__init__(frame)
        self.default_text = ""

    def focusInEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QFocusEvent) -> None:
        if self.text() == self.default_text:
            self.clear()
            if "PASSWORD" in self.default_text:
                self.setEchoMode(self.Password)
        super().focusInEvent(a0)

    def focusOutEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QFocusEvent) -> None:
        if self.text() == "":
            self.setText(self.default_text)
            if "PASSWORD" in self.default_text:
                self.setEchoMode(self.Normal)
        super().focusOutEvent(a0)
```